# delete values from multiple columns

Tags: mysql

i want to delete rows that contains %DJ% and %SD% characters on their value. and also i want this query to check from two different columns. table name 'location', first column name 'start_location' and second column name 'end_location'. This is the sql query i want to perform:

```
DELETE FROM location WHERE start_location like '%DJ%' and start_location like '%SD%'
```

and

```
DELETE FROM location WHERE end_location like '%DJ%' and end_location like '%SD%'
```

so i want to execute this query in one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR`:

```
DELETE FROM location
WHERE start_location like '%DJ%' or start_location like '%SD%'
or end_location like '%DJ%' or end_location like '%SD%';
```

Comment: DELETE FROM location WHERE start_location like '%DJ%' and start_location like '%SD%' is not even working. but DELETE FROM location WHERE start_location like '%DJ%' works.

Comment: You probably want OR everywhere. Try my updated query

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using [MySQL REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator:

```
DELETE FROM location 
WHERE start_location REGEXP 'DJ|SD' AND end_location REGEXP 'DJ|SD';
```

*Note:* If it should delete by **either** column replace `AND` with `OR`